# 'smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected' after many iterations

Tags: python, pandas, smtplib

I am automating the sending of emails by iterating over a DataFrame but after many iterations have this error 'smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected', I don't know what I can do to solve this problem.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.header import Header

filename="my_excel.xlsx"

df=pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Sheet1')
user = 'my_mail'
app_password = 'password'
host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
port = 465

subject = 'Proof'


attachment = "attachment.pdf"

while i<=len(df):
    if df['Status'][i]=='vencido':
        text='my_text'
        to = df['email'][i]
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message['From'] = Header(user)
        message['To'] = Header(to)
        message['Subject'] = Header(subject)
        content_txt= text
        message.attach(MIMEText(content_txt, 'plain', 'utf-8'))
        att_name = os.path.basename(attachment)
        att1 = MIMEText(open(attachment, 'rb').read(), 'base64', 'utf-8')
        att1['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
        att1['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + att_name
        message.attach(att1)
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, port)
        server.login(user, app_password)
        server.sendmail(user, to, message.as_string()) 
        server.quit()
```

Comment: Not sure, but why do you log in for each email? I'd log in once before the loop and then keep sending. Some servers will block you if you send too many emails per connection, some will block you if you open too many connections.

Comment: the login is lost after a certain time, that's why I log in each iteration